# Looping windows programs in script

Tags: vbscript

Scripting windows 7 I need to loop continously from a windows media player play list and when tje playlist is complete to a presentation and then back to the Playlist when the presentation is complete.

Comment: What did you have tried as code until now ?

Comment: Just a batch file that opens the file.

Comment: so looking to see a way to script this... in a time crunch and Iam coming up with nothing...doih!

Comment: Did you have a look at this ? ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761279/play-sound-file-from-within-vbscript-when-msgbox-appears/29808980#29808980